# Pandas: Replacing values using another column as source

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
Source    | Description  |
Incomes   | Tax 12       |
Incomes   | Payment      |
Incomes   | Check 152    |
Incomes   | Incoming 21  |
Incomes   | Receiving    |
Payments  | Tax          |
Payments  | Incoming 7   |
Payments  | Receiving 12 |
Payments  | Check        |
Payments  | Incoming     |
```

First, I replace everything that contains `Incoming` or `Check` to `Incomes` and `Check` using `df.loc`:

```
Source    | Description  |
Incomes   | Incomes      |
Incomes   | Payment      |
Incomes   | Checks       |
Incomes   | Incomes      |
Incomes   | Receiving    |
Payments  | Receiving 2  |
Payments  | Incomes      |
Payments  | Receiving 12 |
Payments  | Checks       |
Payments  | Incomes      |
```

Now I want to replace everything that does not match with `Incomes` or  `Checks` in `Desciption` column with corresponding `Source` value, like that:

```
Source    | Description  |
Incomes   | Incomes      |
Incomes   | Incomes      |
Incomes   | Checks       |
Incomes   | Incomes      |
Incomes   | Incomes      |
Payments  | Payments     |
Payments  | Incomes      |
Payments  | Payments     |
Payments  | Checks       |
Payments  | Incomes      |
```

How I do that?

I already tried `df.loc[df['Description'].str.contains('Incomes|Checks')== False] == df['Source']` with no success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

```
mask = df['Description'].str.contains("Incoming|Check")

df.loc[~mask, "Description"] = df.loc[~mask, "Source"]

df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.replace("Incoming.*", "Incomes") \
    .str.replace("Check.*", "Checks")
```

Comment: Not every row in `Description` has a digit. I know that my original post suggested that, but that is not the case. I already edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you